# Modifying user profile while adding new user fails with "Duplicate entry error"

Tags: python, django

User profile class looks like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    email_my_machines = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    email_others_machines = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name_plural = "Profile"

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Added `"AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'generic.UserProfile'"` in settings.py

Its all working as expected .

In Django Admin, there are two forms involved in adding user. First form has minimal fields such as "username", "password", "password confirmation" and fields provided in "User Profile" class.
When I modify "User Profile" fields in this form, app will crash with error "(1062, "Duplicate entry '34' for key 'user_id'")". It is an Integrity Error.

I am new to Django. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Are you sure that your `post_save` does not fire before the form has a chance to create a new instance (thus making the form fail miserably)?

Comment: No. post_save will not be called. Other thing I observed is, after this crash, I can see user created in auth_user table.

Comment: Make sure you know which part of code causes the exception to raise.

Comment: @patrys: I will try django-debug-toolbar for sql queries.

Comment: @rajpy Have you tried the implemetation of `create_user_profile` from django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Comment: @alexvasi Used the same method but with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I've seen this is when the same signal is fired off twice. Try adding a `dispatch_uid` to your signal connection and it should fixit:

```
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, dispatch_uid='create_profile_user')
```

See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals

Comment: Thanks. It didn't solve the problem. Insert is happening twice:
INSERT INTO `generic_userprofile` (`user_id`, `email_my_machines`, `email_others_machines`) VALUES (40, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO `generic_userprofile` (`user_id`, `email_my_machines`, `email_others_machines`) VALUES (40, 0, 0)
I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: Resolved it. Added "primary_key=True" as    
user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)